# Is it possible to convert between Unicode normal forms in PHP?

Tags: php, unicode

For example, in one Unicode normal form á is always represented as an unaccented letter a and a combining accent mark, in another it must be a single pre-combined Unicode character. How would I convert between these forms in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unicode normalization is provided by the `intl` extension and its `Normalizer` class.

http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.normalizer.php